# I need to generate a unit impulse .wav file?

Tags: python, wav

I need to generate a Dirac delta signal (all zeroes, except for one sample). How can I achieve this?

I have not found [the wave module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using `wave`, actually.

```
import wave

data = [128 for i in range(100)] # zeroes
data[50] = 255 # except for one spike
data = bytes(data) # convert to bytes

with open(r'D:\foo.wav', 'wb') as file:
    f = wave.open(file)
    f.setnchannels(1) # mono
    f.setsampwidth(1) 
    f.setframerate(44100) # standard sample rate
    f.writeframes(data)
```

Here's what the resulting `.wav` file looks like in Audacity: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIzjY.png).

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the unit impulse only defined in the frequency domain?

Comment: Unit impulse is defined in any domain. The Dirac delta is just a signal having a spike of width zero and area equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, sencshin. I was getting confused with what `frames` are.

Comment: @Vorac A "frame" in this context is basically a "sample" which contains information about the height of the waveform at a particular point in time, and your typical .wav file has 44100 samples (frames) per second. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hm, `Exception ValueError: 'I/O operation on closed file' in <bound method Wave_write.__del__ of <wave.Wave_write instance at 0x02296FA8>> ignored` issued both when the file does not exist, or when it does. With `python 2.7.5` on Windows 7. :(

Comment: @Vorac I can't reproduce that on Python 2.7.6 on Windows 7, sorry. Have you made any modifications to the code I posted?